# When cross-referencing a theorem, only the numbers of the chapter and of the section appear

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, tcolorbox

When I cross-reference a theorem, why do only the number of the chapter and of the section appear?

```
\documentclass[x11names,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,breakable}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{thm}{Theorem}{
       before skip=10pt, breakable, detach title, 
       leftrule=2mm, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
       coltitle=black, colback=black!3!white, 
       colframe=black!10!white, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
       arc=0mm, separator sign none, 
       description delimiters parenthesis, 
       terminator sign colon}{theo}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\begin{thm}{}{}\label{thm}
Statement.
\end{thm}
In Theorem \ref{thm}\dots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with theorem-like environments defined with the help of the [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package, you must replace

```
\begin{thm}{}{}\label{thm}
```

with

```
\begin{thm}[label=thm]{}{}
```

This is explained in full detail (maybe even in excessive detail...) in section 4.21, labelled "Counters, Labels, and References", of the user guide of the [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[x11names,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,breakable}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{thm}{Theorem}{
       before skip=10pt, breakable, detach title, 
       leftrule=2mm, before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
       coltitle=black, colback=black!3!white, 
       colframe=black!10!white, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
       arc=0mm, separator sign none, 
       description delimiters parenthesis, 
       terminator sign colon}{theo}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}

%%\begin{thm}{}{}\label{thm} % <-- wrong
\begin{thm}[label=thm]{}{}   % <-- right
Statement.
\end{thm}

In Theorem \ref{thm}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience Mico!